# Scrollable lines/rectangles/ellipses in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a series of rectangles/lines/ellipses via g.FillRectangle etc in a panel which are drawn upon button click (not on form creation).
I would like to be able to have this 'shape' to scroll vertically and horizontally because the number of rectangles and dimensions of this shape varies depending on some parameters so I can 'explore' the entire 'shape'.

Also I would like to be able to add rectangles/lines/ellipses while I am doing this....I am to different parts of the shape.
Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Comment: _drawn upon button click_ I hope you use the Paint event!! Do look into [these post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+autoscrollminsize) !

Answer (score 1):

Create a Panel control on your form called `panel1`, this will be the visible portion of your content.  Set `panel1`'s `AutoScroll` property to *true*.

Inside `panel1`, add a PictureBox control called `pictureBox1`, this will be the large content of your image.

Add a `pictureBox1` Paint handler to draw your shapes inside the PictureBox.

Remember to set the location of `pictureBox1` to 0,0, and set its size to the size of your content.

#### Edit:  Example drawing code

To make use of this example, you'll need need to manually add a `Form` called `Form1`.  In the designer, you will then:

- add the `Panel` and `PictureBox` as described above.
- add a `Paint` handler and a `MouseDown` handler to the `PictureBox`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Point> dots = new List<Point>();

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        const int radius = 4;
        int N = dots.Count;
        if (N == 0) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Click to add a dot", this.Font, Brushes.Black, radius, radius);
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < dots.Count; ++i) {
            var dot = dots[i];
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(dot.X - radius, dot.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, dot.X + radius, dot.Y + radius);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dots.Add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Notice I keep a list of *dots* which is implemented as a form field called `dots` which is a `List<Point>`.  You could keep track of much more data here, and allow for a variety of shapes, more metadata, etc.  The `PictureBox`'s `Paint` handler iterates over all the dots (which represents all your *shape records*) and issues drawing commands to draw each one.  In this example I fill an ellipse and annotate it with a string.  I also added a click handler so you can add dots by clicking.  This updates the `dots` list.  The framework doesn't know that updates to the `dots` list are supposed to cause changes to the visuals in the window, so when you update the list, you have to call `Invalidate` on the `PictureBox` to cause it to redraw again with the new list data (new *shape records* in your case).

`List<Point>` could be easily augmented to `List<Shape>` with a polymorphic `Shape` class of your own design with overridable Drawing methods.

This is all very similar to what Windows Forms Controls offer though, so keep in mind that your idea to just create child controls that do the drawing is valid too, and may even be more convenient if you want to click on them and such.

Comment: You (OP) may need to call 'panel2.Invalidate()' at the end of your button click event to force the panel to redraw.

Comment: I have a couple of questions...  So far I have been using regular FillRectangles etc not linked to Paintevents. I have read in other posts about the necessity of Paint event but I havent really understood why it is imperative.

I have managed to link the Paint handler to do what it should. So far I am accomplishing this through adding of shapes to lists and Refreshing. Is there any other way to accomplish this without keeping a 'record' of what is drawn or is this the way it works? Does this mean that I have to repaint every time I make a change which means that a record is imperative?

Comment: @DimitrisPlatis, a list of controls in the form is tantamount to having a list of rectangles to draw in your paint handler. The control *is* the record. You're just offloading the responsibility of who maintains the list and who draws the rectangles. If you're drawing from your own list in a Paint handler and you change your own list which would affect what gets drawn then, yes, you must `Invalidate` your control at that time. Conversely adding a shape to the form as a control will cause a redraw via that mechanism - no need to explicitly Invalidate anything. But there *is* a record somewhere.

Comment: yes of course there is a record somewhere.....but its different if this record is kept by me..or the system under the hood. 
The problem with the painter method is that I need to put before hand all the possible 'actions' that might happen and if a list has content then enforce that action. 
For example, I would like to be able to have methods for adding shapes/lines, changing the color of existing shapes etc 
As far as I understand it, I have to add all this onto the Paint Handler beforehand and somehow find a way to distinguish when they will produce a result and when not.

Comment: @DimitrisPlatis I added some basic code as an example.  If you want a more sophisticated  example that allows for polymorphic shapes I could create that.  Keep in mind you could always go with your first instinct of just adding more children controls.  Both approaches are valid.

Comment: I will go through ur code and it is much appreciated....and see how thus approach can accommodate what i need. I was also thinking about bitmaps which might allow more versatility

Comment: Regarding the bitmap approach......could I use a bitmap object to draw upon and alter/repaint? 
In this case, I think the advantage would be that I could continuously add to the object/bitmap and use it in different methods....

I am not very familiar with the painting interface...

Comment: You could, but it depends how large the scrollable region is.  Obviously you're talking per-pixel memory requirements instead of per-shape.  Also if the bitmap is the canonical record of what was drawn, the drawing operations are irreversible (can't easily un-draw a shape, like to delete it or move it). Those are two reasons why I wouldn't use a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have a workable solution by utilizing a picturebox in a panel and then using bitmap object which allow a lot of versatility and I can call upon them from wherever I wish.